# iOS: Login to Facebook through app

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to login to Facebook through my app using `FBSDKLoginManager`. I'm asking for some permissions while logging. But every time i get the following error:

> [11624:2243947] data----(null)
>   [11624:2243947] Access Facebook page error:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x15eb2e80 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}

Could anyone please help? This is the code that I've written:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

[login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"data----%@",result.grantedPermissions);
    if (error) {
        // Process error
        NSLog(@"Access Facebook page error:%@", error);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
            // Do work
            NSLog(@" publish actions permission granted");

            [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_likes",@"user_birthday"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    // Process error
                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    // Handle cancellations
                } else {
                    // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                    // should check if specific permissions missing
                    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"user_birthday"]) {
                        // Do work

                        NSLog(@"Permission  2: %@",result.grantedPermissions);
                    }
                }
            }];

        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: I don't suppose this has anything to do with FB completely shutting down their v1 API a week or so ago?

Comment: yes i have solved it by following steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login with Facebook SDK 4.x

Add following code to facebook login button click :

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         // Error
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled)
     {
         // Cancelled
     }
     else
     {
         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
         {
             [self getFBResult];
         }
     }
}];
```

Get Facebook Result Method :

```
-(void)getFBResult
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"fb user info : %@",result);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
             }
         }];   
    }
}
```

You can change the fields of permissions as you want.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot ! i am able to retrieve basic information now. But, I also need to store whether the user has granted publish permission or not. Hence, i'm calling logInWithPublishPermissions after getting the basic information. Publish permissions are also granted but I cannot see the prompt where the user is asked for the permissions. i directly get the response that publish permissions have been granted. Is that because the user is already logged in before? Is there any other way to ask for publish permissions except for using logInWithPublishPermissions?

Comment: I think you are asking about the old API of facebook. Please try to use new SDK @KavitaKanwar

Comment: i'm using FB SDK version 4.1.0. I deleted my app from facebook settings and now it asks me for the permissions. Thanks ! Another thing i'm not too sure about is whether its possible to open facebook app in landscape mode? from whatever I've read online, it seems that its not possible. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, No Idea. about this `logInWithPublishPermissions`

Comment: publish permissions are working fine now, thanks once again! Any idea of whether facebook app can be opened in landscape mode or not?

Comment: Yes i accept your answer. your help is appreciated.